# How to filter Select in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, select

I want to filter by query sql.
Which color of blue, type of boy and size :35,36,39 to choose and display.

For Example: SQL Table (PHPMYADMIN)

```
--------------------------
|id| size | type | color |
--------------------------
|1 | 35   | boy  | blue  |
|2 | 36   | girl | red   |
|3 | 35   | boy  | blue  |
|4 | 37   | girl | red   |
|5 | 38   | boy  | red   |
|6 | 39   | boy  | red   |
--------------------------
```

Here's my code: (PHP):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','datab');
$qu="SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE color='blue' 
    AND size='35' 
    OR size='36' 
    OR size='39' 
    AND type='boy' 
    ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 10";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $qu); 
while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $ro["id"].',';
}
```

Out (HTML):

```
1,2,3,6,
```

I need to out(html) the above records to get "1,3," .

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage your database. It is not a database. It looks like you are asking how to do something in PHP. PHP is a programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` Around OR conditions

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','datab');
$qu="SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE color='blue' 
    AND (size='35' OR size='36' OR size='39' ) 
    AND type='boy' 
    ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 10";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $qu); 
while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $ro["id"].',';
}
```

Comment: alternatively: `WHERE color='blue' AND size IN('35', '36', '39')`

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering the same column for three values, so it makes better sense to use `IN()`; then you don't need to worry with parenthetical grouping of conditions.

```
$qu="SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE color='blue' 
    AND size IN ('35','36','39')
    AND type='boy' 
    ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 10";
```